# Is there a DecrementBy() method in the Performance Counter subject?

Tags: c#, performancecounter

In books I have seen that it exists but MSDN says it does not???

What do you guys have to say on this subject???

Might load up VS later on and see if it appears in 3.5 .Net.  I;m asking as some of you lot know I am lsowly revising for the exam and I don't want little nougets like this to suprise me.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is only an [`IncrementBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.incrementby.aspx) method.

The functionality of a hypothetical `DecrementBy` method can be easily reproduced by passing a negative value to `IncrementBy`.